# hovering over a link in Safari 5.0

Tags: windows, windows-xp, browser, safari

In Safari 5.0, is it possible to be able to view links in the status bar (or somewhere else) before you click on them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to View > Show Status Bar. This is how it's done on Mac OS X, I assume it's similar on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As jtbandes suggested, it was the status bar missing. I mostly use chrome and was looking for a Chrome-like on-the-fly status bar. Totally forgot about the old status bar.

[image]